# How to save each sliced group in illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have a svg spritesheet which I have sliced equally using the slice tool.
[image: Bird_Sprite]

This is what the layers are
[image: Sprite_Layers]

Now, all I want is to be able save each frame as separate svgs. So I am hoping get 10 svgs each containing a single slice. Is there any clever way to do this in Illustator other than manually selecting a group and save and so on.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with Artboards and not slices.
Slices is an old tool of webdesign, not for what you need here imo.

If you place each group in a different artboard, and all artboard have the same size (like you did with the slice) when you hit save as ... you have a checkbox to follow the Artboard  and save multiple files (SVG or not) in a folder, one for each artboard.

Sorry if my english is not perfect, not my mother tongue.

Comment: It worked. Thanks.